# Using Kendo UI with TypeScript 0.9.1 results in many errors in Kendo's definition file

Tags: kendo-ui, typescript

Is there an updated version of the `kendo.all.d.ts` that is compatible with the more strict 0.9.1 version of typescript? I'm getting lots of errors using the current version with TypeScript 0.9.1.

Thanks!

Comment: Where did you get your existing Kendo UI definition? I'd like to see the existing one to see if I can fix it up - but it isn't on Definitely Typed.

Comment: @SteveFenton - Most likely the version that ships with Kendo: http://docs.kendoui.com/howto/typescript/overview

Comment: Unless someone can supply that file, I can't really help.

Comment: I just updated from 0.8.x to 0.9.1 and had to manually update my kendo.web.d.ts file, however this wasn't that much work mostly had to introduce `declare` statements for top level modules. Could you be more specific as to which file you're using?

Comment: Ok using the file that comes with he latest.. Do you have your updated file? Mine broke when I started moving stuff to he top.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may check the forum post here: http://www.kendoui.com/forums/kendo-ui-framework/general-discussions/typescript-0-9-0-support.aspx

Comment: You saved the day with that link. The upgrade of Web Essentials & TypeScript has been *very* painful. Thanks! :)